# Проброс портов openVZ

Tags: iptables, nginx, debian

OS debian 7

**Ситуация такая:**

есть несколько контейнеров openvz

- 192.168.1.121
- 192.168.1.122
- 192.168.1.123

В каждом контейнере есть nginx

nginx так-же есть и на основном сервере. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать следующее:

Когда я запрашиваю адрес основного сервера:
site.ru/test1/, то на я должен попадать на nginx виртуального сервера 192.168.1.121
site.ru/test2/, то на я должен попадать на nginx виртуального сервера 192.168.1.122
site.ru/test3/, то на я должен попадать на nginx виртуального сервера 192.168.1.123

На основном сервере  я написак примеру такой конфиг для виртуалки 192.168.1.121

```
        location /test1 {
                proxy_pass              http://192.168.1.121;
                proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        }
```

Однако, когда я захожу на site.ru я получаю [b]504 Gateway Time-out[/b]

Скорее всего по тому, что просто до виртуалки не доходит коннект. 
Я читал про iptable, что нужно перебросить 80 порт. Но никак не получается это сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: @NEPSTER 4234223, Это вопрос на форум [РутКод](http://admin.hashcode.ru/).

Answer (score 2):

> Однако, когда я захожу на site.ru я получаю [b]504 Gateway Time-out[/b]

Что то не понятно.

Давайте разберемся. По настройке локейшена (который правильно настроен, правда я еще к ип добавляю порт)

```
site.ru/test1 => 192.168.1.121
site.ru/test2 => 192.168.1.122
site.ru/test3 => 192.168.1.123
site.ru/ => ???
```

что с корнем то?

Comment: корень пусть попадает на основной сервер. 


Тоесть у нас идет как:
Основной сервер на нем стоит nginx, который определенные url должен проксировать на виртуальную машину. 

// вот все эти запросы я себе спокойно попадаю на основной сервер, все хорошо 
site.ru
site.ru/doc/
site.ru/redmine/


// теперь обработанные запросы, есть определенный url 
site.ru/test1

И тут он должен попасть уже не на основной сервер, а на виртуальку (openvz)

Comment: смотрите логи. скорее всего проблема в другом

Comment: [error] 4141#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 213.200.48.38, server: мой ip, request: "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.162.1.121:80/index.html", host: "мой ip"

Comment: что то не так с 192.162.1.121 возможно nginx на нем не запущен
попробуйте на основном сервере:

    telnet 192.162.1.121 80

Появится  "Escape character is '^]'." введите:

    GET /

Если все хорошо покажет исходный код index.html

Comment: разобрался:

Добавить настройки:
nano /etc/network/interfaces

iface eth0:1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0

reboot